# addCompleteListener() is not being resolved - Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am wondering why `addCompleteListener()` is not resolved yet I have provided the necessary dependencies :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

I followed this question [Stackoverflow same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282737/cannot-resolve-method-addoncompletelistener/51282857#51282857), but I didn't get any luck.

***Below is my code,I want to get the device registration token :***

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this,new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        String msg = getString(R.string.fcm_token, token);
                        Log.d("--> FCM Token ", msg);

                    }
                });
```

Below is the screenshot :

[image]

What could lead to this issue ?

Comment: I haven't yet done that since I that wasn;t resolving.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: Actually this method is not resolving `addCompleteListener()`, so I haven't utilised the functionality yet.

Comment: It's not allowing to be imported.

Comment: Have you tried to import it manually `import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;`?

Comment: For `FirebaseInstanceId`, it resolved well, but the other didn't

Comment: So the problem comes in after `getInstanceId()` , the intellisense doesn't bring the `addCompleteListener()`

Comment: Show me your error in Android Stuido as a screenshot.

Comment: I have share the screenshot @AlexMamo

Comment: Wherever you see red code is what refused to resolve, but I think this is caused by `addCompleteListener()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

to

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
//                                                  ^^
```

There is no `addCompleteListener` method, it's `addOnCompleteListener()`.

Comment: No it doesn't work, actually it was what I had initially.

Comment: There is no `addCompleteListener` method.I don't understand you. Do you have an error again or? What is the behaviour? What did you have initially? Please show me your current code as a screenshot.

Comment: Actually , addOnCompleteListener(), was the first I had , but somehow it changed , so I found my self posting `addCompleteListener()'. Maybe let me update the question.

Comment: So having `addOnCompleteListener` solved the issue, right? Please edit your question by adding your current code as a screenshot.

Comment: Hey , it has worked, the problem is with the project , it's make some methods look *red* , but it's running well. Thanks.